# Get the value of a particular css element id from child css element

Tags: php, css, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

I am using *Selenium WebDriver* wrapped in *PHPUnit* and *Sausage* to test clicking a button in a specific row in a table that's laid out similar to:

```
<tr id="dynamically generated 1">
    <td class="foo">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </td>
    <td class = "mybutton">
        <span class = "icon clickable"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="dynamically generated 2">
    <td class="foo">
        <div class="baz"></div>
    </td>
    <td class = "mybutton">
        <span class = "icon clickable"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In particular, I want to click a specific element `#mybutton > span.icon.clickable` whose sibling is `.foo` with child `.baz`. The "*whose sibling is `.foo` with child `.baz`*" requirement is the only way I can currently identify the correct element, as other rows in the same table have element `#mybutton > span.icon.clickable`, and the ids for those rows are dynamically generated.

At the moment I am using XPath, but as you might expect, performance on `FF` and `IE` is horrendous. Is there a method for retrieving the value of `tr#id` from the element `tr#id div.bar`? If I can get this, I can use the id to use CSS to find the element I am looking for. I am using PHP, but a solution in any language would be useful.

Alternatively, a more straightforward CSS3 solution would work, but after quite a bit of reading, I've all but concluded that using a standard CSS3 selector is not an option for this case. Just in case there is something I'm missing, is there a CSS3 solution for this? I know there is a CSS4 solution, but I need full browser support, so until all the browsers I am testing support CSS4, I'll have to rely on CSS3.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Until there is better cross-browser support for CSS4, I need to use CSS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this is to find a `List<WebElement>` generated by `By.cssSelector(".foo~span.icon.clickable")` and on each element do a `findElement(By.cssSelector(".baz"))` surrounded by try/catch (catching `NoSuchElementException`s).

When there isn't an error thrown, then you know that you have found your element.

Note:  The `~` selects it if it has ANY proceeding `.foo` siblings.  If you want it to be the immediately previous sibling, use `+`

Comment: Works great. For anyone interested in the php solution:

Comment: For anyone interested in the php solution:  To get all elements that match some criteria:  `$elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('tr'));`  To get the value of some attribute of one of the elements in that list of elements:  `$id = $elements[0]->attribute('tr#id');`

Answer (score 2):

There is no CSS way to select this, because it would require a selector that looks at previous elements, which is not available in CSS3.

However, this would be quite simple in jQuery. I made a selector for your situation

```
$(".foo").has(".baz").siblings(".mybutton").find("span.icon.clickable").addClass('red');
```

- `$(".foo")` - selects elements with a class of `foo`
- `.has(".baz")` - only returns elements that has a sibling with a class of `baz`. In this case, `.foo` with a `.baz` element
- `.siblings(".mybutton")` - looks for an element with the class of `mybutton` on the same level as the previous element. Since we used `has()` instead of `.foo .baz`, this will still target the `.foo` element
- `.find("span.icon.clickable")` - looks for a descending span from the previous element with classes of `icon` and `clickable`
- `.addClass('red');` - just a function to finish the example

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69JWd/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a sibling selector in css called `~` and there are some `css4` selectors which might help.

Perhaps this would work, if I understood the requirement correctly:

```
#mybutton > .foo ~ span.icon.clickable! > .baz
```

This should work in chrome, but its css4 so, it probably wont work in a lot of browsers.

**Hint**: It selects the `span.icon.clickable` which has a child `.baz`

Comment: Thanks. I need a solution that will work with browsers not yet supporting css4, so I'm afraid this won't work for me quite yet. I'll edit my question to specify css3.

Comment: You could use jquery.

Comment: Also @user1721135, the actual selector I'm looking for is `span.icon.clickable` whose parent `.mybutton` has a sibling `.foo` with child `.baz`. Isn't the CSS4 expression for that `.foo! baz ~ .mybutton > span.icon.clickable`?